# Как отправить данные формы в PUT запросе HTTP на Angular 4?

Tags: angular4

Я пытаюсь отправить данные формы обновленных данных пользователя но не как не получается

`{
"name":"User",
"status":1
}`

Как сказать Angular что это

`<input type="text" [value]="user.name" name="name">`

Это Input

**service.ts**

```
updateProductData(dataUrl, id){
        let url = ${environment.endpoint}/${dataUrl}/${id}  ;
        let header =  new HttpHeaders()
            .set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token)
            .set("Accept", "application/json");

        return this.http.put(url, {
            "name":"User",
            "status":1
        },{
            headers: header
        });
    }
```

Comment: У вас не очень релевантный код. Посмотрите в логи браузера и это вам объяснит что работает не так. То что я успел заметить это то что ваш `url` не является **string** для использования string templates используйте ` символ в начале и конце строки. Добавьте Observable<Response> ответ к функций. И где вы ее взываете используйте метод subscribe().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service.ts

```
updateProductData(dataUrl, id): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.endpoint}/${dataUrl}/${id}`;
    const header = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this.http.put(url, {
      'name': 'User',
      'status': 1
    }, {
      headers: header
    });
  }
```

component.ts

```
private dataSub: Subscription;

  update() {
    if (this.dataSub && !this.dataSub.closed) {
      this.dataSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.dataSub = this.service.updateProductData('url', 1)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```